# How to create an organized way of recording sets of data for seven days

Tags: python, python-3.x

Good day everyone

I have a program I need to write which involves inputting data daily for a week. I have no problem setting up how to record for a single day, but I reach a dead end with the rest of the week. Here is some example code for you to help understand my problem:

```
code = []
m1 = []
m2 = []
mt = []

#This is checking for 1 day
code_in = code.append(input())
m1_in = m1.append(input())
m2_in = m2.append(input())
mt_in = mt.append(m1 + m2)
```

Now, my question is: how do I create a system to record these values for 7 days, without having a cluttered list system? One would assume that you would write it as follows:

```
for i in range(7):
    code_in = code.append(input())
    m1_in = m1.append(input())
    m2_in = m2.append(input())
    mt_in = mt.append(m1 + m2)
```

However, I think this is very ineffective. How do I solve this problem?

Comment: Read about python. Do tutorials. Read about File-IO. Do not overwrite the same variables. Read about Lists. Read about module CSV for python. Practice. Combine all that to write the program you need. Restart the programm once a day to input data which is stored into the csv file. **Search** SO for _**python+csv**_ and _**python+ask valid user input**_ Cobble together code that does it for 1 day, extend it. If you encounter problems:

Comment: Please go over [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and 
[on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) again and if you have questions provide 
your code as [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If you encounter errors, copy and paste
the error message verbatim ( word for word) into your question. Avoid using screenshots unless you 
need to convey layout errors. We can NOT copy and paste your image into our IDEs to fix your code.

Comment: Well I would have a class which contains all info about one day, e.g. `class DayData`. Then I would have an `all_days` variable which holds a list of `DayData` instances.